# Tails: How to connect Tails to a Samba network-share?

Tags: configuration, tails, debian, settings, persistent

**Quick question:**

Is there any way to connect `Tails` to a `Samba`-based `shared-folder` in the local network?

**Now the more difficult part is:**

Do I have to configure the `Samba`-server for an access coming from `Tails` in a special way?

I tried to connect to the exchange-folder in three different ways:

1. `smb://HOSTNAME` without success.

   - Causing error: "*Unable to access location. Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection refused*"
2. `smb://WORKGROUP/HOSTNAME` without success.

   - Causing error: "*Unable to access location. Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection refused*"
3. `smb://WORKGROUP/HOSTNAME/Exchange` without success.

   - Causing error: "*Unable to access location. Failed to mount Windows share: Invalid argument*"

---

**My current `/etc/samba/smb.conf` configuration looks like that:**

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
```

and

```
[Exchange]
path = /home/user/Tails-Exchange
guest ok = yes
read only = yes
```

Even if I set the `shared-folder` to `public = yes` and allow `guest ok = yes`, I always get those errors.

---

Thank you very much for your ideas!

[Tails](https://tails.boum.org) = the amnesic incognito live system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, from the top bar of the desktop:

*Applications* -> *Accessories* -> *Files*

On the Files window, on the bookmarks bar on the left, scroll to the bottom of the list and select *Other Locations*.

At the bottom of the *Other Locations* window it says *Connect To Server*, there's a box next to it to type in a server address. Enter a server address, which would look something like this: *smb://192.168.1.2/SharedFolder/* assuming the server is at *192.168.1.2* and the shared folder is shared as *SharedFolder*, then click *Connect*.

It will prompt you for credentials, if they're required otherwise it will default to guest/anonymous access then you'll be able to browse the network fileshare through the file browser.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Do you have any idea how to configure the `Samba`-server to get access from `Tails`? I updated my question to show the current issue.

Comment: Uuuh, no. I'm not much of a samba expert but the `smb://` method has always worked with my NAS.

Comment: Everything is working fine now! It seems like in Linux-based systems it is necessary to access the `Samba`-server with its `IP-address` instead of its `hostname` by default. That means: If I replace the `hostname` with the regarding `IP-address` everything is working completely fine! Thanks a lot! Maybe you can highlight this requirement in your posting... :-)